# Error: EACCES, permission denied when npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions

I know that this topic was talked over few times, but I can't still go through my problem... I totally messed up my NPM and NODE installation. After all, when I am trying to watch (npm start) my foundation project I got result like this:

```
[02:20:51] Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'dist/assets'
[02:20:51] 'build' errored after 5.7 ms
[02:20:51] 'default' errored after 6.91 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MyName/.npm/_logs/2017-08-23T00_20_51_506Z-debug.log
```

DEBUG.LOG

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~prestart: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/MyName/My Repos/viva/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/MyName/My Repos/viva
10 silly lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'gulp' ]
11 silly lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/MyName/My Repos/viva
16 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.4.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
            "name": "foundation-zurb-template",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "description": "Official ZURB Template for Foundation for Sites.",
            "main": "gulpfile.js",
            "scripts": {
              "start": "gulp",
              "build": "gulp build --production"
            },
            "author": "ZURB <foundation@zurb.com>",
            "license": "MIT",
            "devDependencies": {
              "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
              "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
              "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
              "grunt": "^1.0.1",
              "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
              "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
              "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
              "gulp-cli": "^1.4.0",
              "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
              "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
              "gulp-extname": "^0.2.2",
              "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
              "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
              "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
              "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
              "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
              "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.3.7",
              "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
              "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.6",
              "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
              "js-yaml": "^3.9.1",
              "panini": "^1.5.1",
              "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
              "style-sherpa": "^1.0.2",
              "yargs": "^8.0.2"
            },
            "repository": {
              "type": "git",
              "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template.git"
            },
            "bugs": {
              "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues",
              "email": "foundation@zurb.com"
            },
            "babel": {
              "presets": [
                "es2015"
              ]
            },
            "private": true,
            "dependencies": {
              "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
              "svgxuse": "^1.2.4",
              "through2": "^2.0.3",
              "xtend": "^4.0.1"
            }
          }
```

What's more npm instead of path

```
/usr/local/
```

is placed

```
/Users/MyName/.npm-packages
```

I was trying to remove all installation and install again, but still there is same problem...Only sudo helps, but it was not needed before, so I guese there is bigger mess than I suppose...Please HELP!

Comment: I would say delete node.js and every module and start all over... I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I have tried... does not work...

Comment: Do all those settings looks good for you?